# Restrict users with a number of wrong logins

Tags: php

I have a login form in a backend application

I need to find a way to restrict/denied users that for example has entered a bad username/password at least five times and show a meesage like:

```
echo "You have entered wrong 5 times your username/password, you have to wait 10 minutes to the next login"
```

But what do I have to save??

The ip or username? and where to save: file or db?

**EDIT:**

I apologise because I have no been clear in my question

I have implemented this system but using a file instead adding the some fields to the database

I can't paste the code because is huuuuuge and I think I will use the system that I'm using now

Thanks **alex** and **Michael Ames** for your time but can't accept your answers because I was looking for someone that it used file instead database

Comment: Don't you love downvotes with no explanation?  They probably didn't think you did enough background research first, as this is a pretty common scenario and the answer likely already exists out there.  But I thought it was fine.

Comment: yeah maybe is a repeated question but but I thought that store the wrong logins in a file it's was a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise because I have no been clear in my question

I have implemented this system but using a file instead adding the some fields to the database

I can't paste the code because is huuuuuge and I think I will use the system that I'm using now

Thanks **alex** and **Michael Ames** for your time but can't accept your answers because I was looking for someone that it used file instead database

Answer (score 1):

Store all logins made. Store the status of the login (failed or successful) and the date/time. Then query and count the number of sequential failed logins. Then you can check the difference between the current time and the last failed login.

This will give you the most information as well to track down when it happened.

Answer (score 0):

You presumeably have the username and password stored in a backend database somewhere already. Add an integer column to that same table called "FailedLogins", and a date column called "LastLoginAttempt".   Every time they attempt a login, set LastLoginAttempt to the current time. Every time they enter a bad password, increment FailedLogins. Every time they enter a valid password, reset FailedLogins to zero.

You now have all the information stored in the database that you need to write the login logic, which will work like this when they try to log in:

1) If FailedLogins >=5 and it's been less than ten minutes since LastLoginAttempt, tell them they can't login yet.  (Don't even worry about checking the password.")

2) If FailedLogins >=5 and it's been more than ten minutes, reset FailedLogins to zero, then check the name and password.

Good luck!